# Unable to allocate dynamic memory segmentation error

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, dynamic, malloc

I'm trying to allocate memory to an array using a function.
 I have passed pointer by reference(using double pointer). The code compiles but segmentation error is thrown during run time.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
//funct to read array 

int read(int **v){
    int n,ele;
    printf("enter number of elements \n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    //p=(int*)malloc(n*(sizeof(int));
        *v= (int*)malloc(n * sizeof(int)); 
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        //printf("enter %d th element \n",i);
        scanf("%d",&ele);
        *v[i]=ele;
    }
    return n;
}


void main()
{
    int *p=NULL;
    int sz=read(&p);
    for(int i =0;i<5;i++)
    {
        printf("%d",p[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're not checking the return value from `scanf()` so you don't know if it works.  You're not checking to see if `malloc()` returned `NULL` or not because you may have passed it garbage input.

Comment: Post your input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the error: `*v[i]=ele;`. In this case, you've first subscripted array and then have dereferenced it.
https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence. Change it to `(*v)[i]=ele;` and it will work.

**UPD.** Don't forget to `free(p)` to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: This isn't C++.

Comment: @JL2210 i've attached link for c operator precedence, not c++, but the answer would remain the same for c++

Comment: I know. You mentioned `operator[]`.